# Prevent white space from bootstrap columns with different heights that have been reordered

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Using twitter-bootstrap for my responsive layout and am running into an issue where the first 3 columns (full 12 sections) is creating unwanted white space for the next column.

[Example of white space I wish to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1VTC.png)

I have created a jsbin with my current issue.
https://jsbin.com/puvaqaluzi/edit?html,output

The columns have been reordered for the desktop and mobile sizes and the goal is to keep them in the same order.  When the red column is smaller than the two beside it (yellow and green columns) it creates white space above the last column, the teal one.

I do not want to increase the red columns height and would rather pull the teal column upwards, using only CSS if possible.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3" style="height: 300px; background-color: red;">
            <h1 class="text-center">Mobile 1</h1>
            <h1 class="text-center">Desktop 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-6" style="height: 200px; background-color: yellow;">
            <h1 class="text-center">Mobile 2</h1>
            <h1 class="text-center">Desktop 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="height: 400px; background-color: green;">
            <h1 class="text-center">Mobile 3</h1>
            <h1 class="text-center">Desktop 3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3" style="height: 500px; background-color: teal;">
            <h1 class="text-center">Mobile 4</h1>
            <h1 class="text-center">Desktop 4</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you might want to look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Comment: @minum the colums will auto wrap if the count is greater than 12

Comment: I have re-read this about 6 times and am still not clear what it is you want to happen. Also as a good habit you should paste your code in the question or use the integrated "snippets" instead of pastebin

Comment: if i am understanding this you want the columns to be red, yellow, green teal on mobile in one "column". What do you want to happen on desktop? Red yellow, green in one row then teal underneath yellow?

Comment: @happymacarts I have added a picture and the code, hopefully that helps.  In short, on the desktop view I want to remove the white space created by the varying heights of the first 3 columns

Comment: @happymacarts In regards to your question before, the current order of the columns in the jsbin is correct, only thing I need help with is removing the white space above the teal column so it is directly below the red column on desktop.

Comment: are the heights of those sections fixed? If so since you are "hardcoding" the heights you may have to create some media queries to set the heights to what you need.

Comment: The heights will be changing dynamically depending on the content in each of the sections.

Comment: Easy to do with flexbox and about 4 lines of css. Just stick them all in a flexbox container, and utilize align-items, align-content, and flex-wrap . You dont need the bootstrap grid classes to do this at all. The Bootstrap grid is not the way to go if you are using blocks of varying height.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: there may be some browser specific support issues with flexbox depending on your audience

Comment: Looks like it will only impact 1-2% of users. 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @korgue should post that as an answer seems like that a beter solution than what i have been working on. I will post mine as well in case he "has" to use bootstrap grid

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to fix this and continue using bootstrap grid, just to be consistent with the rest of the site, but if flexboxes are the only way to achieve this then I guess I will have to read up on it.

Comment: @david lee what is controlling the height of your sections (inline styles , dynamic hard coded)?

Comment: @happymacarts the height of the columns will be determined by text within each, this text will be entered by users so it can vary.

Comment: do you plan to set a max and/or min height for those divs?

Comment: @happymacarts I do not plan on setting any hard limits on the sizes of each column

Answer (score 0):

I worked up this as a possible solution. add the colored classes to your divs (instead of inline styles)
note this is only working when the heights are known or controlled by class

@korgue's comment to use flexbox may be a better solution since you will not be setting limits unless you plan to add some js.

**css**

```
.red {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
.yellow {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.green {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
}
.teal {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: teal;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .red,
  .yellow,
  .green {
    min-height: 400px
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3 red">
        <h1 class="text-center">Mobile 1</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">Desktop 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-6 yellow">
        <h1 class="text-center">Mobile 2</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">Desktop 1</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 green">
        <h1 class="text-center">Mobile 3</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">Desktop 3</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3 teal">
        <h1 class="text-center">Mobile 4</h1>
        <h1 class="text-center">Desktop 4</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/hahogigosu/edit?html,output

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but I am looking for a solution that does not require changing the height of the columns, but rather the position of the last column.

Comment: Not sure why but the snippet is reordering the css the media Q should run after the other piece. i added the jsbin

Comment: ok. bootstrap grid doesn't work that way they must be in rows. Unless you are to put the teal content in the same div as the red div

Comment: Seems like the only solution to get the desired result is by using flexboxes as Korgrue stated, thanks for the help tho.